# What's the easiest way to get just the top-level text of an XmlElement?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

Suppose I have some `XmlElement`; let's call it `element`. If I want to get all of the child nodes of that element, I can call `element.ChildNodes`. If I want the text of the element *and all its children*, then I can go with `element.InnerText`.

However, suppose I have some XML that looks like this:

```
<TopElement attr1="value1" attr2="value2">
    This is the text I want.
    <ChildElement1>This is text I don't want.</ChildElement1>
    <ChildElement2>This is more text I don't want.</ChildElement2>
</TopElement>
```

If I go with `element.InnerText`, what I get is this:

> This is the text I want.This is text I
>   don't want.This is more text I don't
>   want.

If I want just the text within TopElement but NOT any of its children, I can do this:

```
Dim txt As String
For Each child As Xml.XmlNode In XmlElement.ChildNodes
    If TypeOf child Is Xml.XmlText Then
        txt = child.InnerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

But this seems quite silly to me. Surely there is a better way?

**EDIT**: Sorry I didn't specify this initially: I'm looking for a solution not involving LINQ (we're in the Dark Ages over here with .NET 2.0).

Comment: I would have thought using .Net 1.0 or 1.1 would be the Dark Ages. ;)

Comment: I would say .NET 1.0 and 1.1 were the Ice Age, 2.0 was the Dark Age, 3.5 was the Renaissance, and 4.0 is some kind of sci-fi fantasy world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression that specifically looks for a text node (sorry for the C#)

```
XmlText text = doc.SelectSingleNode("/TopElement/text()") as XmlText;
if (text != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text.Value);
}
```

(Where `doc` is an `XmlDocument` containing your XML)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the text within the TopElement is a childnode.

```
class Program
{
    static string xml = @"<Top>Text<child/><child/></Top>";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

        Console.WriteLine(xdoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem I see with this answer is that it assumes ChildNodes[0] will be text. I don't know for sure that there will be top-level text; I want to see IF there is, and if so, to get it.

Comment: Absolutely.  I don't see anything wrong with the solution you've provided above.  InnerText takes the text of all childnodes.  If you want the text of a specific childNode, you will have to iterate through them to find it.

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(yourXml);

//Find the first child whos type is XmlText
var nodeYouWant = document.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.OfType<System.Xml.XmlText>().FirstOrDefault();
```

**Edit**

Since you can't use LINQ, you can still use the good ol' XQuery and request the node text

```
XmlNode nodeYouWant = document.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("./text()");
```

This will work even if the text you want is between the two child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim txt As String

If TypeOf XmlElement.FirstChild Is Xml.XmlText Then
        txt = XmlElement.FirstChild.InnerText
End If
```

Comment: I like this answer; however, it does assume that if there is top-level text, it will be the first child. Consider something like this: <elem1><elem2>Unwanted text</elem2>Wanted text</elem1>. In this case your code would miss the wanted text.

Comment: if the text can be anywhere between child nodes, an iteration is needed and your solution is great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that will give you the request text:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var document = XDocument.Load("../../TestXmlFile.xml");

            if(document.Root == null) return; 

            var text = ((XText) document.Root.FirstNode).Value; 

            Console.WriteLine(text);

        }
```